# Elegant Ruby one liners

Tags: ruby

One of the reasons I like writing in Ruby so much is because it is very capable of achieving a lot via one liners.

I like:

```
@sentence = @sentence.split(' ').map!{|x| x = x[0..0].upcase << x[1..-1] }.join(' ')
```

It capitalizes the first letter of each word, which is not the most stunning, but quite efficient.

What's the most elegant one liner you have seen or written with Ruby?

Comment: Please edit and mark this as a community wiki, to avoid having it closed for being subjective (no real answer) :)

Comment: The ability to mark questions community wiki was removed a time ago. See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down

Comment: I wouldn't call that "elegant", because it is almost unreadable. If another programmer encounters this code, they will have to spend several minutes reading it to figure out what it is trying to do. It's more cryptic than elegant. You have saved keystrokes at the price of readability.

Comment: In your example, why not use `string.capitalize`? Granted it's possibly doing more than you want (it lowercases the rest of the string)

Comment: @Matchu: you [*can't* mark a question as community wiki anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192). It [just kinda happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) automatically. (I don't know what prevents an answer from being closed as too subjective.)

Comment: It isn't a one-liner for me - the `')` occurs on a second line because it's so long!

Comment: So Ruby is the programming language Arnold Schwarzenegger would write in?

Comment: Schwarzenegger always struck me as more of a Fortran kinda guy.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You posted the oneliner:

```
@sentence = @sentence.split(' ').map!{|x| x = x[0..0].upcase << x[1..-1] }.join(' ')
```

But you misunderstand a couple things about Ruby.

First off, saying `x=` in a map call doesn't affect anything outside of the map call. The new value of that array element is the value *returned* by the block.

Secondly, you don't need to mutate the first string with `<<` -- a concatenation that creates a new string (using `+`) is a much better option.

Thirdly, `map!` makes changes directly to the array returned by `split`. What you want to do is leave that array untouched (even though it doesn't change program semantics), and return a new array with the mapped results, by using `map`.

So you should have written:

```
@sentence = @sentence.split(' ').map{|x| x[0..0].upcase + x[1..-1] }.join(' ')
```

Now the statement `x[0..0].upcase + x[1..-1]` is still very obtuse. Maybe you should replace it with the `capitalize` method, which already changes the first letter of the string to uppercase. (Note that it also downcases all of the others, which may or may not be what you want.)

```
@sentence = @sentence.split(' ').map{|x| x.capitalize }.join(' ')
```

I'd probably use `gsub!` to change parts of the string in-place, but that's probably a little obtuse:

```
@sentence.gsub!(/\S+/){|x| x.capitalize}
```

One more thing. If the only purpose of a block is to call a single method on the object passed to the block, you can do the following:

```
@sentence = @sentence.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

or to modify my `gsub!` version:

```
@sentence.gsub!(/\S+/,&:capitalize)
```

Comment: Just now, you've either completely shattered his spirit, or he has absolutely tripled his excitement for one-liners.

Comment: I was hoping to learn a lot from the responses here, and Ken's comment has been a perfect educational journey!  Definitely x3'd the one liner excitement

Comment: +1 `@sentence = @sentence.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')` is what I'd call elegant.

Comment: @CravingSpirit: `:something` is a symbol, in this case for the name of a function. `&` converts it to a `Proc` by calling `to_proc` on the symbol. When you call `to_proc` on a symbol, it creates a function that calls the method with that name on its first argument. (so `:capitalize.to_proc()` creates a lambda `foo` that when you call `foo(a)`, it calls `a.capitalize`)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Ruby Quiz #113](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz113.html).

Answer (score 1):

Open a file, write to it, and close it in one line:

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'assets', 'file.txt'), 'a+') {|f| f.write("stuff"+"\n" }
```

Most of my best Ruby one-liners in every day scripts utilize `and`, `unless`, `if`, `&&` and so forth, like:

```
puts "x is nil!" if x.nil?
```

You can use `unless` and `if` interchangeably, but `unless` significantly improves readability when used correctly:

```
puts "bad input type!" unless ["bs", "cf", "is"].include?(type)
```

Oftentimes, the best Ruby one-liners are ultimately done in two to three lines of one-liners working together, often in conjunction with Ruby's "valence" system for variables (`nil` and `false` are the only "negatives"):

```
def try_first(actual_index)
    x = [get_header(actual_index, 0), get_data(actual_index, 0)] unless get_header(actual_index, 0).blank?
    x = try_second(actual_index) if x[0].blank? #blank is a rails method, detects nil and empty strings and empty containers ([]) I think too
    puts "x is nil!" if x.nil?
    x
end
```

I say one-liners composed of several one-liners because that method itself is less than a one-liner somewhere else in my code. Many of my methods just one line though:

```
def get_all_coords(type)
  eval("@#{type}_coords")
end
```

That's how you really start to get elegant. Break out code into individual methods. One-line methods are perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci number for sure!

```
def fib(n, t = n < 2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)) t; end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wrote one a few days ago but couldn't use it as an answer because the question was closed by then.
It replaces the first line of a file with a string if the string isn't already there.

I hope someone improves on this one also:

```
ruby -i.bak -pe "print ($_!~/string/ && $.<2) ? \"string\n\":''" filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci sequence generator:

```
def fib n;n==0?[0]:n==1?[0,1]:(2..n-1).inject([0,1]){|a|a<<(a[-1]+a[-2])};end
```

same as:

```
def fib n;n<2?(0..n-1).to_a():(2..n-1).inject([0,1]){|a|a<<(a[-1]+a[-2])};end
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely this emulation of GREP (Windows user). [[credit goes to Dave Thomas](http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/ruby/ruby-one-liners.html)]

```
ruby -pe 'next unless $_ =~ /regexp/' < file.txt
```